# How to display multiple instances of products list, each by category id

Tags: magento2, product, category, blocks, template

I have this code and it displays the product name and product url by category id. 
Question 1 = How do I add the product image to the echo? 
Question 2 = How can I change the code so I can use multiple instances of the code (in same template file) with different category id's?

**Block file:**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Block;
class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_categoryFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCategory($categoryId) 
    {
        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
        $category->load($categoryId);
        return $category;
    }

    public function getCategoryProducts($categoryId) 
    {
        $products = $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
        $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        return $products;
    }
}
```

**Template file:**

```
$categoryId = 6; 
$categoryProducts = $block->getCategoryProducts($categoryId);
foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {
    // print_r($product->getData());
    // printing category name and url
    echo $product->getName() . ' - ' . $product->getProductUrl() . '<br />';
}
```